# Program exiting without core file after socket::send

Tags: c++, c, sockets

This is a section of the server code.  When the client exits, the server program dies without coring after the following line:

```
n = send(s, buf+total, bytesleft, 0);
```

Here is the function:

```
static ssize_t conn_Send(int s, u8* buf, ssize_t len)
{
  ssize_t total = 0;        // how many bytes we've sent
  ssize_t bytesleft = len;  // how many we have left to send
  ssize_t n;

  while(total < len)
  {
    n = send(s, buf+total, bytesleft, 0);
    //abort();
    if (n < 0)
    {
      return n;
    }
    total += n;
    bytesleft -= n;
  }

  return total;
}
```

I have looked in the obvious places: /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern is set correctly, and indeed the program exits with a core file if the "//abort();" is commented out above.

Any ideas?  I'm at wit's end.

Comment: Use a debugger to figure out what's going on. I don't see how we could help you with this, we'd need the whole call stack & corresponding code.

Comment: If n < 0 you should call perror() or friends, immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When the client exits, the server program dies
>
> ```
> n = send(s, buf+total, bytesleft, 0);
> ```

This is typically the result of getting killed by `SIGPIPE` when the other end closes the connection. There are quite a few ways to getting around this, including:

- You can use `setsockopt` with `SO_NOSIGPIPE`
- You can use `MSG_NOSIGNAL` as a `send` flag
- You can ignore `SIGPIPE`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  I ran through gdb and got "Program terminated with signal SIGPIPE, Broken pipe. The program no longer exists."  I'll be trying SO_NOSIGPIPE.

Comment: @fission You can also get a pretty good indication of how it died by checking the return status `$?`.